# specify "--network=host" using spring-boot:build-image

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I've been using `docker build` this way:
`docker build  --network host -t foo/bar`

But now I'm trying to make use of `spring-boot:build-image`

`mvn spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=foo/bar`

but this way `--network` option is not provided. Unfortunately didn't find a way how to properly provide the option.

**Question**: How can I provide `--network` with `spring-boot:build-image` (assuming I need to provide this option during `build` and not during `run`)?

Comment: Why do you need to disable Docker's networking stack, especially during the build process?

Comment: @DavidMaze those are the requirements ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer. Apparently this feature is available **since Spring Boot 2.6.0-M2**
see:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25876 and
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.6.0-M2

Starting with this version you can try to do something like

```
<project>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <network>host</network>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```